# Gsheet: Combining 2 ranges fo different sizes and schema

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for help combining two tables with different  schema (although with common columns). The tables have a different column ordering too.

Table 1 has 3 columns,

> last name,    city,   id

Table 2 has 3 columns as well,

> name, id, city

Desired output is a master table that combine both tables where
Table has 4 columns with the following schema

> city, name,   id, last name

where if there is no value available for table 1 or 2, they should be blank/null in the master

I've attached the data in this spreadsheet and the method I have approached
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/188tovL_g189H6HjzJAvq1H-65p385R2N7MmWckqb9Jw/edit?usp=sharing

I'm using Query() to reorder the tables based on a manually defined schema.
but when combining, I fail to add placeholders columns.
I think my struggle is to get some placeholders columns in the QUERY parameter.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think stacking query()s on top of one another should work, provided that you use a placeholder that "Looks" like it's empty, like a space....

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY('raw sheet 1'!A3:C,"select B,A,C,' ','  '");QUERY('raw sheet 1'!E3:G,"select G,' ',F,E,'  '")},"where Col1<>''",0))
```

Comment: Another possibility might be a series of stacked HLOOKUPS() of a different tab each, inside a query.

Comment: Nailed it. thanks a ton for your help
when using the same number of columns in the Query Param, i end up seeing the first value for the first imported row as " "(), "   "(), ... any thoughts?

query for table 1
Select Col9,Col10,Col13,Col12,Col17,Col20,Col21,Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col7,Col8,' ','  ','   ','    ',Col16,Col11,'     ' where Col1 <>''
query for table 2
Select Col9,Col10,Col14,Col13,' ',Col17,Col22,Col1,'  ',Col3,'   ',Col5,'    ',Col7,'     ',Col8,Col12,Col19,Col11,Col21 where Col1 <>''